# ASP.NET MVC - Cannot upload more than 5 files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am using `HttpPostedFileBase` for uploading files in MVC. It is working fine when I upload 5 files at a time. But as I select more than 5 files, even 6 files it won't work and save functionality is also not working while I select more than 5 files.

This is my ActionMethod for saving other data with uploading files.

ActionMethod

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEditCoffinCasketItem(CoffinCasketItemModel model)
{            
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        // Some code

        if (coffinData.ID > 0)
        {
            if (model.Image != null)
            {
                coffinData.ThumbImageUrl = CommonHelper.UploadFile(SystemEnum.EntityType.Coffin.ToString(), model.Image);
            }

            if (model.Image360 != null)
            {
                coffinData.Image360FileSize = CommonHelper.ToKiloBytes(model.Image360.ContentLength);
                coffinData.Image360Url = CommonHelper.UploadFile(SystemEnum.EntityType.Coffin.ToString(), model.Image360);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            coffinData.ThumbImageUrl = CommonHelper.UploadFile(SystemEnum.EntityType.Coffin.ToString(), model.Image);
            if (model.Image360 != null)
            {
                coffinData.Image360FileSize = CommonHelper.ToKiloBytes(model.Image360.ContentLength);
                coffinData.Image360Url = CommonHelper.UploadFile(SystemEnum.EntityType.Coffin.ToString(), model.Image360);
            }

            if (model.IsBuildYourOwn == true)
            {
                coffinData.TopImageUrl = CommonHelper.UploadFile(SystemEnum.EntityType.Coffin.ToString(), model.TopImage);
                coffinData.BottomImageUrl = CommonHelper.UploadFile(SystemEnum.EntityType.Coffin.ToString(), model.BottomImage);
            }
        }

        int id = this.coffinService.SaveCoffin(coffinData);

        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in model.LargeImage)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                CoffinCasketImage coffinImage = new CoffinCasketImage();

                coffinImage.LargeImageUrl = CommonHelper.UploadFile(SystemEnum.EntityType.Coffin.ToString(), item);
                int coffinImageId = this.coffinService.SaveCoffinLargeImage(coffinImage);
            }
        }

        this.TempData["msg"] = string.Format(Messages.MessageTypeSave, ExtentionMethods.GetEnumDescription(SystemEnum.Category.Coffin.GetHashCode() == model.CategoryId ? SystemEnum.EntityType.CoffinItem : SystemEnum.EntityType.CasketItem));
        this.TempData["status"] = SystemEnum.MessageType.success.GetHashCode();
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Coffin", new { categoryId = model.CategoryId });
    }
}
```

UploadFile Method

```
public static string UploadFile(string uploadDir, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            string second = dt.Day + "_" + dt.Month + "_" + dt.Year + "_" + dt.Hour + "_" + dt.Minute + "_" + dt.Second;
            fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName) + second + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string serverPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Upload/");
            string filePath = Path.Combine(serverPath, uploadDir, fileName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(serverPath, uploadDir)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(serverPath, uploadDir));
            }

            file.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return "/Upload/" + uploadDir + "/" + fileName;
}
```

Web.config

```
<system.web>
    // other stuff
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength ="2097151"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- Limit file uploads to 55MB -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="57671680"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

What to do with this problem ?

Comment: total size of those six files?

Comment: less than 1MB. precisely 532 KB. @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, no error at all, but on Save button click, action method is not getting hit, and this issue occurs only when i try to upload more than 5 files. It is also okay with 5 files, I can upload 5 files at once. but not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in the past. Now I am using Http-Multipart-Data-Parser, where all images are merged in the single stream object. 
Refer this page: https://github.com/Vodurden/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser

```
public string UploadImages(Stream imgstram)
    {
        var parser = new MultipartFormDataParser(imgstram);
        foreach (var file in parser.Files)
        {
            //file => stream of single image.
            //convert stream to image
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to use it? Can post an example for it?

Comment: This blog of code is my WCF service function. And you can get MultipartFromdataParser lib from reference Github example.